# Как задать в переменную объект из DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Учусь jQuery, написал вот такой скрипт http://jsfiddle.net/hspouwnx/14/ суть в том что нужно получить текст из `div` с классом `message`, если напрямую в документе есть этот `div` то проблем нет я получаю эти данные вот так `var text = $(".message").text();` но если данные прилетели с AJAX или были созданы динамически то этот метод их не выбирает.

Прошу помощи и пути решения данной проблемы

Comment: Find можно юзать чтобы найти новый элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тот момент когда вы получаете значение, элемента нет в DOM,
но если искать при событии все будет хорошо.
Немного измененный код из вашего примера http://jsfiddle.net/hspouwnx/14/

```
$('#shop_msg2').click(function () {

var text = $(".message2").text() || "Текста нет";  

$.MyStick({ 

    note: text,
    // или вообще так
    // note: $(".message2").text(),
    className: 'message',
    position: {
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
    },
    time: 3000,
    speed: 300
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Присвоение значения переменной text2 происходит при загрузке страницы. А при загрузке страницы в .message2 пусто, поэтому запоминается пустое значение. И потом оно не меняется, т.е. навсегда остаётся пустым. А если переместить получения значения внутрь функции, так text2 будет получать значение при каждом клике на кнопку заново и когда значение появится, text2 изменится с пустоты на текст который появится в #shop_msg2 :*

```
$('#shop_msg2').click(function () {
    var text2 = $(".message2").text();

    $.MyStick({
        note: text2,
        className: 'message',
        position: {
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0
        },
        time: 3000,
        speed: 300
    });
});
```